# Secure Boot is enabled and cannot be toggle off in Bios

Tags: bios

The problem is pretty self explanatory. I am using bios 2103 on an Asus Z87-Expert. I need to disable secure boot for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004013/tensorflow-isnt-using-nvidia/39845649#comment127028446_39845649) reason. My machine dual boots to windows or linux mint using Grub. See picture for problem.

[image: Secure Boot state greyed out.]

Here's the other half of the screen if that's helpful. I can't find any useful documentation.

[image: Unhelpful information.]

If this is not considered a Unix/Linux question, please direct me to the appropriate exchange. Thanks!

Comment: bios version is irrelevant unless we know which motherboard (or laptop) this is

Comment: also try looking at the "security" tab/screen if there is one

Comment: @Esther Added mobo model. The security tab just has supervisor password options. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Welcome, you can try to set the password for the admin.

Comment: Please, go carefully through all uEFI/BIOS menu. In my computer, I had a similar problem: if I disabled the secure boot, after restart I found the secure boot enabled again. In the last menu tab, there was another feature: restore the default settings after restart! This must be disabled, too. You may have to find something similar in your BIOS.

Comment: Many systems have Windows or Other as setting. Then  under Other you can choose to boot in UEFI without Secure boot or old BIOS/CSM/Legacy mode. You still want to boot in UEFI mode.

Comment: Please write an Answer that describes the solution, and mark the question as answered. That will stop this question from popping up as "unanswered" time and time again, highlights it as "solved" for others looking for answers to similar questions, and you will get some reputation from it too. (There is nothing wrong in answering your own question.)

Answer (score 1):

Some BIOS/EFI must have the administrator password to change some options.

Go to the *Security* tab and set the password, then you will have access to privileged options.

The rationale would be that security configurations could only be accessed by the administrator.

Be careful **not to forget the password**, in any case set it to something trivial like `1234`.

Comment: I set the password and reset, but it is still greyed out :(

Comment: @BenAlan Oh, I was sure it was it. By reset you mean that you saved the changes and reboot?

Comment: Yup. I tried to see if was fixed before rebooting. It wasn't. Then I rebooted, entered the password, and it was still greyed out.

Comment: @BenAlan select OS type to windows, and let's see.

Comment: That ...worked. It made "Secure Boot Key options" visible. *Disclaimer: I don't know if this can damage your system.* In that menu I selected "delete secure boot keys." Secure Boot is still greyed out, but now it is disabled. Linux and Windows boot fine still.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity or BenAlan, Please write an Answer that describes the solution, and mark the question as answered. That will stop this question from popping up as "unanswered" time and time again, highlights it as "solved" for others looking for answers to similar questions, and you will get some reputation from it too. (There is nothing wrong in answering your own question.)

Comment: @telcoM I think you intended the comment to be below the question, here I don't see what can I do, and OP won't be notified unless they are following the answer (assuming they are active).